# C : Using substr to parse a text file

Tags: c++, file, parsing, substr

I just need a little help with file parsing. We have to parse a file that has 6 string entries per row in the format:

"string1", "string2", "string3", "string4", "string5", "string6"

My instructor recently gave us a little piece of code as a "hint," and I'm supposed to use it. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to get it to work. Here's my file parsing function.

```
void parseData(ifstream &myFile, Book bookPtr[])
{

    string bookInfo;
    int start, end;
    string bookData[6];

    getline(myFile, bookInfo);
    start = -2;

    myFile.open("Book List.txt");

    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
        start += 3;
        end = bookInfo.find('"', start);
        bookData[j] = bookInfo.substr(start, end-start);
        start = end;
    }



}
```

So I'm trying to read the 6 strings into an array of strings. Can someone please help walk me through the process?

Comment: Your instructor gave you that piece of code.  I'd suggest that you change courses, because that's a very bad way to go about it.

Comment: I concur with James. I've included what is arguably a "better" approach for parsing out a quoted-string multi-line file. It isn't perfect, but its far better than the "hint" your instructor gave you (which is a "hint" to-be-sure, but one that has more to do with their proficiency than addressing this specific problem).

Answer (score 1):

```
start = -2;
for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
{
    start += 3;
    end = bookInfo.find('"', start);
    bookData[j] = bookInfo.substr(start, end-start);
    start = end;
}
```

So `", "` is four characters.  The leading closing quote is 3 characters behind the opening closing quote.

At entry to the loop `start` is pointing to the last closing quote.  (On first entry to loop it is faked as `-2` to be pointing to the closing quote of the imaginary "-1th" element.)

So we advance from the last closing quote to the following opening quote:

```
    start += 3;
```

Then we use std::string::find to find the closing quote:

```
    end = bookInfo.find('"', start);
```

The offset tells it to ignore all characters up to and including that position.

We then have the two quote positions, `start..end`, so we use `substr` to extract the string:

```
    bookData[j] = bookInfo.substr(start, end-start);
```

And we then update start for the next loop to be the last closing quote:

```
    start = end
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, for your own sake, create a minimal example. This starts with a string like the line you gave as example and ends with the different parts in an array. Leave the loading from a file out for now, getline() seems to work for you, or? Then, do not declare every variable you might want to use at the beginning of a function. This is not ancient C, where you simply had to do that or introduce additional `{}` blocks. There is another thing odd, and that is the `Book bookPtr[]`. This is indeed just a `Book* bookPtr`, i.e. you are not passing an array to a function but just a pointer. Don't fall for this misleading syntax, it's a lie! Anyway, you don't seem to be using that pointer to the object(s) of the unknown type anyway.

Concerning the splitting of a line into strings, one approach is to locate pairs of double quotes. Everything in between is one of the strings, everything without is irrelevant. The string class has a find() function which optionally takes a starting position. Starting position is always one behind the previously found position.

Your code above seems to assume that there is exactly one double quote, a comma, a space and another double quote that separates two strings. This isn't 100% clear, I would also be prepared for handling multiple spaces or no space at all. Also, is the comma guaranteed? Are the double quotes guaranteed? Anyway, keep it simple. Unless you get a better spec on the input, just assume that only the parts between the quotes is what differs.

Then, what exactly works and what doesn't? You need to ask more specific questions and give more detailed information. The code above doesn't look broken per se, although there are a few things a bit off. For example, you don't typically pass ifstreams to a function, but use the istream baseclass. In your case, you read a line from that file and then open another file using the same fstream object, which doesn't make sense to me, since you don't use it after that. If you only needed that stream locally, you would create and open it there (handling errors of course!) and pass in the filename as parameter only.